# How to connect AWS OpenSearch Serverless to Lambda to inject data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, opensearch

I'm trying to do a PUT request to upload data to a collection I have created. However, I'm getting a '403' error; 'User does not have permissions for the requested resource'.

I believe I have granted full IAM access to the user but I'm still getting the same error.

Here is the IAM and function within my serverless file:

```
   iam:
    role:
        statements:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                  - aoss:*
              Resource:
                  - '*'

functions:
    lambdaFunction:
        handler: src/controllers/lambdaFunction.handler
        description: create a lambda 
        events:
            - http:
                  path: /lambda
                  method: post
                  cors: ${self:custom.cors-settings}
                  private: false
                  authorizer:
                      type: CUSTOM
                      authorizerId: ${self:provider.environment.authorizer_ref}
                      resultTtlInSeconds: 0
        memorySize: 256
        logRetentionInDays: 30
        iamRoleStatementsInherit: true
        iamRoleStatements:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                  - aoss:*
              Resource:
                  - '*'
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation unluckily is not one of the best, but first off you need to create a data access policy inside your Opensearch Serverless collection where you add a rule with:

- as Principal: your lambda role
- as grants/permissions: based on what the lambda should do with the collection

[image]

[image]

If you don't know your lambda role, you can just go to your lambda detail page and then navigate to 'Configuration > Permissions' and its sitting right on top of that page

[image]

After that you should give to the lambda role the access policy to perform the aoss:APIAccessAll action. Now I didn't find any 'pre-made' access policy so I created a new one with name **OpensearchServerlessAPICaller** with the following json policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "aoss:BatchGetCollection",
                "aoss:APIAccessAll"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

With everything in place now your lambda can perform calls directly to your Opensearch Serverless collection. Remember to correctly authenticate the library's client you are using. I suggest using @opensearch-project/opensearch if you are using node, which would mean that you should create the client with:

```
import { AwsSigv4Signer } from '@opensearch-project/opensearch/aws';
import { Client } from '@opensearch-project/opensearch';
import { defaultProvider } from '@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node'

const client = new Client({
  node: "Your opensearch host",
  ...AwsSigv4Signer({
    region: 'eu-central-1',
    service: 'aoss',

    getCredentials: () => {
      const credentialsProvider = defaultProvider();
      return credentialsProvider();
    },
  }),
});
```

Sidenote: Keep in mind that if you opted to protect your opensearch collection within a VPC then you should place the lambda within the same VPC otherwise it's not going to reach the collection.

Comment: JSON was not working for me.